# How to copy the file into SharePoint documents library folder using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint

I'm working on a Access DB to store files in a network location rather than as attachments in Access. The code is supposed to copy file from a local drive into a network location using

```
FileCopy strSource, strDest
```

I would like to use SharePoint documents library as a target storage location.
How can I provide a path to SharePoint document library folder?

I tried:

- Providing URL of the folder
  "https://name.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/Shared Documents/"

with different variations of forward and back slashes and "%20" for space

- Mapping SP folder a network drive is unsuccessful. I get error message:

[image]"

The regular (non SharePoint) network drive address works without problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, `FileCopy`, `Dir`, `MkDir`, the `FileSystemObject` methods, etc, etc, only work with regular file paths. HTTP paths are an entirely different thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Sync feature in Sharepoint to a local folder on your PC. Copy files to the local location and the Sync feature will automatically upload them to your Teams Channel.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not feasible for the multi user app . Each user may have different path mapped, pointing to the same SP folder.